# How stored procedure returns from multiple cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have Oracle Stored Procedure below and I understood most of the logic inside except for the part where the caller of the procedure will get all the values from different cursors.

Did some reading that SP returns the OUT part in a procedure parameters shown in the sample below. But i fail to get any reference as to how p_returnCode can store resultsets from queries inside the stored procedure.

Procedure retrieveX(p_date date, p_loc varchar2, p_returnCode out integer)

The stored procedure below have 3 cursors cur1, cur2 and cur3. How or where does it store the values? Cur1 contains 2 columns with multiple rows and Cur2 and Cur3 contains one column with multiple rows.
Can anyone clarify this part?

Caller from cgi script

```
report.retrieveX(p_date,p_loc,p_return)
```

Full Stored Procedure

```
PROCEDURE retrieveX(
    p_date DATE,
    p_loc VARCHAR2,
    p_returnCode OUT INTEGER
)
AS

    TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
    cur1 cur_typ;
  cur2 cur_typ;
  cur3 cur_typ;
    query_str VARCHAR2(2000) := '';
    query_str2 VARCHAR2(2000) := '';
    query_str3 VARCHAR2(2000) := '';
    v_an VARCHAR2(20);
    v_tn VARCHAR2(20);
    v_sOID varchar2(20);

BEGIN

sqlRouteDT := 'AND  sp.ROUTE_DT = TO_DATE(''' || TO_CHAR(p_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD') || ''',''YYYY/MM/DD'')';

IF p_loc IS NOT NULL THEN
  sqlLocation := 'AND   act.location_cd = ''' || p_loc || '''';
END IF;

    p_returnCode := 0;
    query_str := '
                    SELECT distinct
                       sp.ab,
                       y.track,
                    FROM ship sp
                       inner join activ act on sp.soid=act.on
                       inner join peace y on act.on=y.soid
          where
             sp.man is not null
             ' || sqlLocation || '
             ' || sqlRouteDT || '
                    ORDER BY sp.ab asc
        ';
    OPEN cur1 FOR query_str1;
    LOOP
      FETCH cur1
      INTO
        v_AN,
        v_FN
      EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;

      query_str2 := '
        SELECT DISTINCT INTER_CD
        FROM    TBL_INTR
        WHERE   AF = ''Y''
          AND   sOID = ''' || v_sOID || '''
        ORDER BY INTER_CD
        ';
      OPEN cur2 FOR query_str2;
      LOOP
        FETCH   cur2
        INTO    v_intr_cd;
        EXIT WHEN cur2%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INTER_CD|' || v_intr_cd);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur2;

      query_str3 := '
        SELECT DISTINCT hi_cd
        FROM    tbl_hi
        WHERE   AF = ''Y''
          AND   sOID = ''' || v_sOID || '''
        ORDER BY    hi_cd
        ';
      OPEN cur3 FOR query_str3;
      LOOP
        FETCH   cur3
        INTO    v_hi_c;
        EXIT WHEN cur3%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hi_cd|' || v_hi_c);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur3;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
EXCEPTION   WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_returnCode := 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END retrieveX;
```

Comment: I don't think, `p_returnCode` is being used to return any data. Its being used to just mark, if the procedure is going into exception. I believe, whoever wrote this code only wanted to do `dbms_output.put_line()` to view data on script output

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so, how does it run? `v_soid` is not declared anywhere! As to your question, it looks like whoever wrote this (IMHO, terrible) code has attempted to reinvent nested loop joins, left their code wide open to SQL injection, relying on dbms_output.put_line to output the results of looping through the tbl_intr and tbl_hi tables, and then outputting the success/failure of the procedure via a parameter. Oh, and hiding the actual error message by outputting it via dbms_output.put_line.

Comment: yes this is the actual code and it works fine in generating reports. I just want to understand a bit more as to how it returns data back to the caller. I updated the code as to how it is called

Comment: I'm sure this code will not run. There is a `;` missing after the first `FETCH`.

Comment: Also, where is v_soid defined? Your initial cursor is opened and the details are fetched into v_an and v_fn, but your other two cursors don't "join" on either of these two variables. So if this is a procedure inside a package, and v_soid is defined elsewhere, you will be querying the exact same query (e.g. cursor 2) multiple times for each row in cursor 1. Is that really what you want?

Comment: i forgot to copy a few other variables i updated the code. Its not what i want this code is already working and the reports generated is being used. I just want to understand it better. Its a legacy code which is written inside a bash script. Then there are multiple cgi scripts that call this procedure to retrieve the data.

Comment: p_returnCode just says if everything was fine or not. I dont understand the question asking "how p_returnCode can store resultsets from queries"

Comment: @dimas what populates v_soid? Usually, in this type of code, you'd expect v_soid to be output by the first cursor, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think possible to do that you want.

Maybe you should to considerate the use of pipelined function, please take a look at https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

With this technique, you can write a pl/sql code to access to complex data and relationship table and get the result as a simple

```
 select * from StoredProcedure(Parameter_1...);
```